# how to render content in the component that is loaded by useEffect- React

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I have a component into which I am fetching data. As expected the component renders first and then the useEffect. The trouble is that this useEffect fetches data that I need rendered in my component. Anyway I can make the content in the component load after the useEffect propagates data to the useState?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/global/layout/Layout';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import styles from '../components/page-css/menu.module.css';
import MenuItemHolder from '../components/menu-page/menuItemHolder/menuItemHolder';

const Menu = () => {
    const [ menuItems, setMenuItems ] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios('https://tahina-test.herokuapp.com/doggos');
            setMenuItems(result.data);
            
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <Layout textColor="white">
            <Col>
                <Row className={styles.menuHolder}>
                    <Col className={styles.menu} xs="11" md="8">
                        <h1>Menu</h1>
                        <Row>
                            {menuItems.records.map((item) => (
                                <MenuItemHolder name={item.Name} price={item.UnitPrice} />
                            ))}
                        </Row>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Col>
        </Layout>
    );
};

export default Menu;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, you are asking how to only render the `MenuItemHolder` components when the data has been fetched and the state has been populated with this data.

There are two ways to achieve this:

**#1** Initialize `menuItems.records` with an empty array:

```js
const [ menuItems, setMenuItems ] = useState({records: []});
```

such that on the initial render, `menuItems.records.map([...])` will return an empty.

**#2** Render the `MenuItemHolder` components based on a condition:

```
<Row>
    {menuItems && menuItems.records.map((item) => (
        <MenuItemHolder name={item.Name} price={item.UnitPrice} />
    ))}
</Row>
```

This will work since the initial value of `menuItems` is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the `menuItems` beforehand, so accessing `menuItems.records` will be valid.

```
const Menu = () => {
  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState({ records: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    //...
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  // records are empty until data fetch
  return (
    <>
      {menuItems.records.map((item) => {
        /*...*/
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Menu;
```

Or just use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper):

```
const Menu = () => {
  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    //...
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  // Conditional rendering
  return (
    <>
      // Same as menuItems && menuItems.records
      {menuItems?.records.map((item) => {
        /*...*/
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Menu;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `loading` state to render loading element while `fetchData` is fetching data from server.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/global/layout/Layout';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import styles from '../components/page-css/menu.module.css';
import MenuItemHolder from '../components/menu-page/menuItemHolder/menuItemHolder';

const Menu = () => {
    const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(false);
    const [ menuItems, setMenuItems ] = useState({records: []});

    const fetchData = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        const result = await axios('https://tahina-test.herokuapp.com/doggos');
        setLoading(false);
        setMenuItems(result.data);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    return (
        <Layout textColor="white">
            <Col>
                <Row className={styles.menuHolder}>
                    {loading ? (
                       <Col className={styles.menu} xs="11" md="8">
                            Loading, please wait...
                       </Col>
                    ) : (
                        <Col className={styles.menu} xs="11" md="8">
                            <h1>Menu</h1>
                        
                            {menuItems.records.map((item, index) => (
                                <Row key={index}>
                                    <MenuItemHolder name={item.Name} price={item.UnitPrice} />
                                </Row>
                            ))}

                        </Col>
                    )}
                </Row>
            </Col>
        </Layout>
    );
};

export default Menu;
```